# Replicate indexing output from MATLAB's union in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have a data set that has a large number of elements where each data element has a time, some metadata, and a value. There are many separate data types in the set. All information is numerically coded and stored as a numpy array. I need to sort this 1xn data stream into an array where each row is a unique time and the columns represent different data at that time. I have solved this problem in MATLAB (different ways, but story for another time) using MATLAB's union function. I'd like to replicate this in python, but I've been stuck for a few days trying to get this done.

I have extracted the unique sorted time values into a 1xm array (`a` in the below example). I have also extracted each element for a data type, which is also unique and sorted (`b` in the below example). `b` is always a subset of `a`. The following MATLAB code shows how this works.

```matlab
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,4,7,10]
[C,ib,ia] = union(b,a)
C =1
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
ib =
     1
     2
     3
     4
ia =
     2
     3
     5
     6
     8
     9
mask = ones(size(a))
mask(ia)=0
data_column(mask == 1) = data_vector(ib);
```

The output `ia` are the indices of `a` which do not correspond to values in `b`. Using `ia` to make a logical mask, I can then quickly assign the data to the correct rows in the desired row-column output array format.

In python `numpy.union1d(b,a)` gives the output `C`, but not the indices; which is what I'm trying to find here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions posted here, I've found my way to an fairly concise answer. using the `numpy.intersect1d()` function I was able to return the indices I was looking for. As in the following: where `m` is column index, `data_column` is originally all `nan` the length of `a`, and data_vector is the length of `b`

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,4,7,10]
[C,ia,ib] = numpy.intersect1d(a,b,assume_unique=True,return_indices=True)

print(C)
[ 1  4  7 10]

print(ia)
[0 3 6 9]

print(ib)
[0 1 2 3]

data_column[ia,m] = data_vector
```

The `return indices` feature is key. I found this by reading about numpy set functions, which I found through the submitted answers. I just didn't know where to look, thanks all!

Comment: You asked about `union`, then answer about `intersection`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you assume the following:

- `a` and `b` are both sorted
- `b` is a subset of `a`
- numpy library is available in the environment
- indices are not required, only values are required

Could you use `numpy.setdiff1d`?

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> b = [1,4,7,10]
>>> numpy.union1d(a,b)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> numpy.setdiff1d(a,b)
array([2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Thanks for our input, I am actually looking for the indices, rather than the values. Your answer put me in the right direction though, so it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own `union` function, using `unique` and some sorting.

```
import numpy as np

def union(a, b):
    ua = np.unique(a)                           # get unique values in input a
    ub = np.unique(b)                           # get unique values in input b
    c = np.concatenate((a, b))                  # combine a and b
    C, ic = np.unique(c, return_index=True)     # call unqiue and return incides

    sel = ic > (a.size - 1)         # every index larger than a.size comes from b
    ia = ic[~sel]
    ib = ic[sel] - a.size

    return C, ia, ib
```

And your test:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> b = np.array([1, 4, 7, 10])
>>> [C, ib, ia] = union(b, a)
>>> C
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> ib
array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
>>> ia
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
```

Of course the indexes are off by one, since Matlab starts indexing at 1 and Python at 0.